# Errors installing sqoop on Mac

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to set up sqoop to run sql queries from databases and store the tables in HDFS.

I've installed sqoop version 1.99.3 and download the directory contents to `"~/sqoop/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/"` on my local machine.  Then, following the instructions I found [here](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Installation.html), I executed the command.

```
./sqoop.sh server start
```

Many of the other steps in the documentation require using the command "sqoop", but my bash prompt doesn't recognize that command:

~/sqoop/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/bin 15:30:22]$ sqoop
-bash: sqoop: command not found

Does anyone have guidance?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the installation location of the sqoop binary isn't in your $PATH.  You might consider referencing the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

I know this isn't going to be the top answer, but it's my first answer.  Someone will hopefully be along eventually who knows the actual product.

Another thing to try is to locate the binary for sqoop, navigate into that directory, and use "./sqoop youroptionshere -foo -bar" instead of just "sqoop youroptionshere -foo -bar".  That might be better than adding tons of directories to your $PATH

Comment: I added these lines to my bash_profile: export SQOOP_HOME="########/sqoop/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200"
export PATH="$PATH:SQOOP_HOME/bin"           but still no luck

Comment: You may need to remember to restart your bash session or log back in.  I forget what causes $PATH changes in bash config files to change.  Have you tried yet running the sqoop binary directly from it's installation location?

EDIT: Also, is the binary's executable flag set?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently [2 versions](http://ingest.tips/2014/10/21/sqoop-1-or-sqoop-2/) of [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org) that are very different from each other: [Sqoop 1](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html) and [Sqoop 2](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.4/).

You are using Sqoop 1.99.3 it seems, which is an early release of Sqoop2. Check out the [5 minute demo](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Sqoop5MinutesDemo.html) to get a sense of what's going on.